# Efficient way to join two tables only for the records having values of a var from the third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, plsql

I have two big tables:

```
A: (ID1,VAR1);
B: (ID1,ID2,VAR2)
```

And a third table:

```
C: (ID2...)
```

I'd like to merge A and B only for the records having values from C.

Below is my thought by using "IN". Is there a more efficient way to do this? Sometimes I found that "IN" does not work so well.

Thanks a lot!

```
select  A.VAR1,B.VAR2
from A 
INNER JOIN 
(
  select ID1,VAR2
  from B
  where ID2 in
                (select distinct ID2
                 from C
                )
) D
on A.ID1=D.ID1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use the subqueries, you just need to do a `JOIN` on all of the tables:

```
SELECT A.VAR1, B.VAR2
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.id1 = b.id1
INNER join
(
    SELECT DISTINCT id2
    FROM c
) c1
    ON b.id2 = c1.id2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select A.VAR1, B.VAR2 
from A 
INNER JOIN B on A.ID1 = B.ID1 
INNER JOIN C on B.ID2 = C.ID2
```